# How to remove Schema fields using PowerShell script

Tags: web8.5, powershell

I want to remove Schema fields using a PowerShell script.

Any one have suggestion and solutions?

Comment: You want to remove a field from a schema, or from the components (or both?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can establish a Core Service connection from Powershell to the CM and then use the Core Service API to perform the desired action.

Just one question though, why do you need to remove schema fields from Powershell in the first place, for me it doesn't seem the most logical way/place to do it.

Comment: it`s business requirement remove the schema fields. specific fields no more use in future.

Comment: Yeah, but any specific reason for choosing Powershell?

Comment: Indeed, why not do this in the GUI? How many schemas do you have?

Comment: We have multiple teams and multiple  release a month. we have nearly 300+ schema`s. I don`t want to revert other project changes in this schema. power-shell script just remove specific schema field without impact other fields and also best away.

Answer (score -2):

schema fields remove not possible using shell script. I removed schema field in development and content porting in production environment.

Comment: You most certainly can do this via powershell, we just don't seem to understand _why_ you'd want to do this..